# Can I associate the account with Facebook after it was already created?

Tags: facebook, draw-something

My wife has created a Draw Something account directly, not using Facebook as the login mechanism, but she now regrets doing that. Can she associate the existing account with Facebook somehow, or does she have to create a new account (and lose all her coins) if she wants to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, for one just go to draw something, hit the settings button in the top right, and tap help. It will take you to a help section, and your question is the very top one listed... 
I'll re-type the reply here for you:

> If you've already created an account vie email, and you want to play
>   with your Facebook friends, you'll have to log in with your Facebook
>   account.
>
> If both your Facebook account and Email account share the same email
>   address, our system will TRY and keep your existing email account
>   games.
>
> Ready to give it a shot? Here's what you need to do if you've already
>   logged into your email account:
>
> 1. Press the gear in the top right of the game.
> 2. Click on account
> 3. Scroll down to the bottom of the page.
> 4. Press Log Out
> 5. Login with your Facebook account
>
> Again if your FB account email matches an existing email account of
>   yours, it'll try to retain your stuff. If it doesn't, your new FB
>   account will be separate. (Sorry, we can not transfer games, coins,
>   bombs, colors over.)
>
> In the future we are looking to make this process way easier. Thanks!

Word for word ;) Hope this helps!

Comment: No  problem :) Glad to have helped.